# JAXB - Checking to see if a child element is present

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I think this question should be quick and easy for some of you more experience JAXB'ers. I simply need to check wether or not a child element is present as I'm unmarshalling a XML file.

Currently I'm getting the `java.lang.NullPointerException` error and I think it's because I'm trying to create an object (the child element) that doesn't exist. Here's a simple example.

```
<Meter>
  <MeterSessionInput>
    <MeterSessionOutput>
      <MeterSessionOutputOptical>
```

The MeterSessionOutputOptical child can be present, but doesn't have to be. I would like to check to see if the element exists before attempting to declare its object counter-part.

Comment: I actually found a way, but perhaps someone else can possibly give me a better way of doing. Within the MeterSessionOutput object, the method to get the instance of MeterSessionOutputOptical can evaluated in a simple if statement.                `MeterSessionOutput mso = meter.getMeterSessionOutput(); if(mso.getMeterSessionOuputOptical() != null){ .... }`

Comment: What `NPE` are you hitting?  If the `MeterSessionOutputOptical` element is not present then your JAXB implementation will not realize it as an object.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan The `NPE` was from when I tried to create an instance of `MeterSessionOutputOptical` without checking whether the child element existed. There are a large number of `meters` in the XML file and I'm looping through them all. Some have the MeterSessionOutputOptical, some do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment is the answer. Simply perform a null check on the child element with an `if` statement. You should be doing this anyway unless your using xsd and mandating that the subelement(s) element exists at binding time.